# ORACLE select query with order by case ASC and DESC

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have data like this:

```
ID | FTIME                 | STATUS
1  | 2020-02-27 08:11:12   | C-in
1  | 2020-02-27 08:11:15   | C-in
1  | 2020-02-27 08:11:18   | C-in
1  | 2020-02-27 17:11:01   | C-out
1  | 2020-02-27 17:11:03   | C-out
1  | 2020-02-27 17:11:08   | C-out
```

Assume the table name is `TBL_RECORD`

Now I need distinct to get data only with this case below:

1. For status C-in, only get data ascending, means it will be `2020-02-27 08:11:12`
2. For status C-out, only get data descending, means it will be `2020-02-27 17:11:08`

So the result will be:

```
ID | FTIME                  | STATUS
1  | 2020-02-27 08:11:12    | C-in
1  | 2020-02-27 17:11:08    | C-out
```

I have tried my below code but it's not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, FTIME, STATUS FROM TBL_RECORD ORDER BY (CASE STATUS
          WHEN 'C-in' THEN FTIME ASC
          WHEN 'C-out' THEN FTIME DESC
      END) DESC
```

Is there any way to get the lucky query?

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @TheImpaler Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1):

I think, we have to restrict number of records in output so we have to use `group by` instead of `order by`. Please try below query -

```
SELECT
    ID,
    (CASE STATUS WHEN 'C-in' THEN MIN(FTIME) ELSE MAX(FTIME) END) AS FTIME,
    STATUS
FROM TBL_RECORD
GROUP BY ID, STATUS;
```

I think you need below query (`Group by` data by `Status` only)-

```
SELECT
    (CASE STATUS WHEN 'C-in' THEN MIN(FTIME) ELSE MAX(FTIME) END) AS FTIME,
    STATUS
FROM TBL_RECORD
GROUP BY STATUS;
```

If you need data only for `ID = 1` then you have to add `Where` clause in query like below -

```
SELECT
    ID,
    (CASE STATUS WHEN 'C-in' THEN MIN(FTIME) ELSE MAX(FTIME) END) AS FTIME,
    STATUS
FROM TBL_RECORD
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY ID, STATUS;
```

Comment: Hi, tried your code but its not correctly show the data. You can see on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f585/1

Comment: Hi, what is incorrect in this result? Do you need ID in output? I think you can group by STATUS only.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Oracle.

In Oracle 12.1 you can perform a union between two `SELECT`s that limit to 1 row.

For example:

```
(
  select *
  from tbl_record
  where status = 'C-in'
  order by ftime
  fetch next 1 rows only
)
union all (
  select *
  from tbl_record
  where status = 'C-out'
  order by ftime desc
  fetch next 1 rows only
)
```

**EDIT FOR ORACLE 10g**:

In Oracle 10g you can do:

```
select * 
from tbl_record 
where status = 'C-in'
  and ftime = (select min(ftime) from tbl_record where status = 'C-in')
   or status = 'C-out'
  and ftime = (select max(ftime) from tbl_record where status = 'C-out')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the code. But when I have more than 1 ID. It show me only 1 ID data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82f6b/1

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Your question does not mention the ID. Please change the question or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This one will work for multiple IDs.

If you're just using ID, FTIME and STATUS, `GROUP` functions will work well. If you're pulling other columns please let me know and I'll show an alternative that's a bit more involved.

To get oldest by ID for `C-in`:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, MIN(FTIME) AS OUT_FTIME
FROM TBL_RECORD
WHERE STATUS = 'C-in'
GROUP BY ID, STATUS;
```

To get newest by ID for `C-out`:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, MAX(FTIME) AS OUT_FTIME
FROM TBL_RECORD
WHERE STATUS = 'C-out'
GROUP BY ID, STATUS;
```

To put it all together:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, MIN(FTIME) AS OUT_FTIME
FROM TBL_RECORD
WHERE STATUS = 'C-in'
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
UNION SELECT ID, STATUS, MAX(FTIME) AS OUT_FTIME
FROM TBL_RECORD
WHERE STATUS = 'C-out'
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
ORDER BY ID, OUT_FTIME;
```

Comment: Hi, What I want is the data will show only 2 for each ID (in and out). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed2e9/2

Comment: Oh, crap - I tanked the query by using `FTIME` instead of `STATUS` in the `GROUP BY`. Sorry about that. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing a fiddle. My updated answer is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed2e9/4.